# Gradle android loses catch clause

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, try-catch

I have following code in my library project:

```
catch (GeneralSecurityException|IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I compile it through Gradle, in source code I see this:

```
catch (GeneralSecurityException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Why `IllegalArgumentException` catch clause disappeared during gradle build?
PS. If it's important, library is included via Jitpack.

**Update. Here is my build.gradle files.**

***Project file.***

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

***Library file.***

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
group='com.github.Tap-Payments'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0'
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}
```

Comment: Post your `build.gradle` files.

Comment: @JaredBurrows, updated a question, thanks.